# How can I replace LSTM with BERT?

Tags: lstm, bert-language-model

I need to use BERT instead of LSTM in this example. Is it possible to just replace the word LSTM with BERT?

```
inputs1=Input(shape=(2048,))
  
fe1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(inputs1)

inputs2 = Input(shape=(max_length,))

se1 = Embedding(vocab_size, 256, mask_zero=True)(inputs2)

se2 = LSTM(256)(se1)

se3 = Dropout(0.5)(se2)

decoder1 = Concatenate()([fe1, se3])

decoder2 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(decoder1)

outputs = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(decoder2)

model=Model(inputs=[inputs1,inputs2],outputs=outputs)
```

or how can I start to use it, please?

I tried this:

```
inputs1=Input(shape=(2048,))
fe1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(inputs1)
inputs2 = Input(shape=(max_length,), name="input_ids")

in_mask = Input(shape=(max_length,), name="input_masks")
in_segment = Input(shape=(max_length,), name="segment_ids")

bert_inputs = [inputs2, in_mask, in_segment] 
bert_output = BertLayer(n_fine_tune_layers=12, pooling="mean")(bert_inputs) 

decoder1 = Concatenate()([fe1 bert_output])

decoder2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(decoder1)

outputs = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(decoder2)
    
model=Model(inputs=[inputs1,inputs2],outputs=outputs)
```

but got:

```
 bert_output = BertLayer(n_fine_tune_layers=12, pooling="mean")(bert_inputs) 
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'pretrained_model_path' and 'output_size'
```

Answer (score 2):

BERT is a pretraining technique. It uses transfer learning to use previous knowledge in a new setting. Thus, to use BERT you need to specify a pre-trained model name or path. So, NO, you cannot simply replace LSTM to BERT.

Look at the answers to this question: [How to create a BERT Layer with Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61467389/how-to-create-a-bert-layer-with-keras)

Comment: thanks a lot for replying. excuse me ..if I need to use bert for image captioning . is there any way like the code I posted to do this? I mean most of the methods to do that use encoder and decoder but I need to do this like the code in the post

Comment: You're welcome. You can try adding 'pretrained_model_path' and 'output_size' parameters as suggested in the error message. I am not sure if it works @Lei

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to use Sentiment Classification with LSTM and pre-trained BERT embeddings, and later language translation with Transformer
first of all I downloaded

```
!pip install ktrain
!pip install tensorflow_text
```

And I imported the necessary lib

```
import pathlib
import random
import numpy as np
from typing import Tuple, List

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# tensoflow imports
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (
    TextVectorization, LSTM, Dense, Embedding, Dropout,
    Layer, Input, MultiHeadAttention, LayerNormalization)
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import Constant
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
import tensorflow_text as tf_text 
import ktrain
from ktrain import text
```

And I downloaded and extracted Large Movie dataset from Stanford

```
!wget https://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/aclImdb_v1.tar.gz
!tar -xzf aclImdb_v1.tar.gz
```

1- I try to use LSTM with train by Creating the training and test sets with the texts_from_folder function of the ktrain.text module

```
%reload_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
%matplotlib inline
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID";
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0";

DATADIR ='/content/aclImdb'
trn, val, preproc = text.texts_from_folder(DATADIR,max_features=20000, maxlen=400, ngram_range=1,                                               preprocess_mode='standard', train_test_names=['train', 'test'],classes=['pos', 'neg'])
```

And I am trying to build LSTM model her

```
K.clear_session()    
def build_LSTM_model(
        embedding_size: int,
        total_words: int,
        lstm_hidden_size: int,
        dropout_rate: float) -> Sequential:
    model.add(Embedding(input_dim = total_words,output_dim=embedding_size,input_length=total_words))
    model.add(LSTM(lstm_hidden_size,return_sequences=True,name="lstm_layer"))
    model.add(GlobalMaxPool1D())
#     model.add(Dense(total_words, activation='softmax'))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
    model.add(Dense(MAX_SEQUENCE_LEN, activation="relu"))
#     adam = Adam(lr=0.01)
    model.compile(loss='CategoricalCrossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.01), metrics=['CategoricalAccuracy'])
    model.summary()
    model = Sequential()
```

with the following requirements  for a sequential model The model should include:
One Embedding layer at the beginning. (Watch out for proper parameterization!)
At least one LSTM layer.At least one Dropout layer for regularization.One final Dense layer mapping to the outputs.
compile model, with categorical_crossentropy loss and the adam optimizer. or might want to add other types of metrics for example CategoricalAccuracy makes sense here.

And then I want to use the **ktrain library**'s **get_learner** method to create an easily trainable version of the previous model. and to use test set as the **val_data**, to see the performance. ( not include the proper train-validation-test split, but it could be extended if required.)
I am using the  **learner's** **lr_find** and **lr_plot** methods to determine the most effective learning rate for the model. by Specifying the **max_epochs** parameter of **lr_find** to limit the time this takes.  a couple of epochs! to determine the best learning rate based on the plot. and find balance between the fastest convergence and stability

```
learner: ktrain.Learner
model = text.text_classifier('bert', trn , preproc=preproc)
learner.lr_find()
learner.lr_plot()
learner.fit_onecycle(1e-4, 1)
```

I faced following errors
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
6 #                              workers=8, use_multiprocessing=False, batch_size=64)
7
----> 8 model = text.text_classifier('bert', trn , preproc=preproc)

```
     10 # learner.lr_find()
1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ktrain/text/models.py in _text_model(name, train_data, preproc, multilabel, classification, metrics, verbose)
    109         raise ValueError(
    110             "if '%s' is selected model, then preprocess_mode='%s' should be used and vice versa"
--> 111             % (BERT, BERT)
    112         )    113     is_huggingface = U.is_huggingface(data=train_data)
ValueError: if 'bert' is selected model, then preprocess_mode='bert' should be used and vice versa
```

And next step to make it with **LSTM with pretrained** static word vectors